# Please clarify my mistake while doing the dry run

Tags: python

The following code is all correct but I have a doubt. While I am doing the dry run I find in my mind that it should show 2 as NOT a prime number. Someone please clarify how the code is running all good.

```
num = 4
if num > 1:
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")

else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

Comment: Hi, I can see that this issue could be avoided by using the Test Driven Development :-) I highly recommend learning about Clean Code and TDD :-) For python you could use `pytest` :-)

Answer (score 0):

2 is a prime number, but your code will shows 2 as *not a prime number*

Here is the fix:

```
num = 4
if num > 2:
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")

elif num = 2
    print(num, "is a prime number")

else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```